# Public project management online program

Tags: web-apps, project-management, hosted

I'm looking for a project management tool that is public and allows users to login and view current bugs and feature requests, submit new ones, or comment and vote on them, and ideally receive notifications when their request has been acted upon.

I would also like to be able to close outstanding requests along with a message and potential description of how the request was settled (and if it was a bug fix, add *private* notes about the code and how it was fixed).

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of tools for this. Popular open source ones include Bugzilla, Redmine, trac, and Mantis. Google "issue tracker". If you want a free hosted one, there's github and sourceforge (and probably others).